# Maximal angle of vision of a screen

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, maxima-minima

A $40$ feet high screen is put on a vertical wall $10$ feet above your eye-level. How far should you stand to maximize the angle subtended by the screen (from to bottom) at your eye?

My solution goes like this:

> If the person  is at a distance $x$ from the wall-screen arrangement, then we obtain a right-angled triangle of base $x$ feet and height $40+10$ feet. If the angle subtended from the screen to the person's eye level is $\theta$, then we have, $\tan\theta=\frac{50}{x}.$ Now, $\tan\theta$ is maximum as $\theta\to\frac{\pi}{2}$( since $\tan\theta\to\infty$ as $\theta\to\frac{\pi}{2}$)  thus, $x=0.$

Now, I think something is wrong with my solution, but I just don't know the reason why? Is this solution valid? If not, where is it going wrong ?

Comment: @coffeemath Can you please elaborate the meaning of : "circle lying in the vertical plane orthogonl to the wall " ?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiomontanus%27_angle_maximization_problem (you don't want to include the angle going down to your eye-level in the angle to be maximized).

Comment: (continued) The above assumes the viewer is just an eye actually on the floor. It can easily be adjusted if one knows how hight off the ground the viewer eye is.

Comment: @boojum Thanks a lot! I do get it now!

Comment: @Franklin Just deleted my comments because the geometric solution is explained in the wiki link given by user boojum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your method maximises the angle subtended by the screen *and the 10 feet below*. However, how much of that angle is due to the screen depends on distance.

To elaborate (see Empy's comment): If you're very close to the wall, you mostly see the ten feet of empty wall, because that's closer to your eyes, and a tiny strip of scree above that. When you're very far away, the height above your eye level doesn't matter much anymore, and the screen will be four times as large as the empty wall below; however, everything becomes smaller as you move away. Then, there is a sweet spot where the screen angle is maximal.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by " how much of that angle is due to the screen depends on distance. " ? The maximized angle is when $\theta=\frac{pi}{2}$ and then $x$ should be $0$. 

Comment: The ten-foot wall covers most of the $\pi/2$, leaving a small angle for the screen on top.